# What's wrong my windows service on windows 2012?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written multiple windows services in one exe & created setup/deployment package to install on destination server (windows 2012). I can see all services in Services & able to start them but it is not performing required action..Weird!!

Program.cs

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                {
                    new service1(),
                    new service2(),
                    new service3()
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace MyService
{
    partial class service1: ServiceBase
    {
        public service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\temp\\Text1.txt", true);

            str.WriteLine("text");

            str.Close();
            try
            {
                //more functionality
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("done", "done desc", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Error", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
}
```

When I start service1 manually, it doesn't perform any action..Neither I see text file getting created nor any error/info in event log. What's wrong? Am I missing something wrong???

Appreciate for help!

Comment: Debug the service. You'll have to do that anyway sooner or later when the code becomes more complex. Just looking at the code does not help you find the error. Investigate.

Comment: put your try arround the streamwriter

Comment: I tried placing System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); on start & installed in debug mode but nothing happened.

Comment: `Debugger.Break();`. And: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=.net+debug+service (help yourself).

Comment: well, no luck with Debugger.Break()